# Deserializing JSON response which differ in each response

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I have complicated JSON respone which containt about 100 attributes/objects/arrays and have difrrent responses in terms of object/array.

Firstly I have structure like that (when object exists)

```
{
    'att1': 'desc',
    'att2': '83482',
    'att3': null,
    'test': {
        'object_array1': [
            100
        ],
        'object_array2': [
            'desc'
        ]
    }
}

public class Root
{
    //fields here
    public Test test { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
    public List<int> object_array1 { get; set; }
    public List<string> object_array2 { get; set; }
}
```

The issue I have is when this objects is empty.
After that resposne is changing and returning empty array.

So it is chaning to this:

```
{
    'att1': 'desc',
    'att2': '83482',
    'att3': null,
    'test': [

    ]
}
```

And beacause of that I have standard error:

> Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Test' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

I was trying to write customconverter with something like that:

```
    private bool IsArray(string fieldName, JObject jObject)
    {
        return jObject[fieldName].Type == JTokenType.Array;
    }
```

I'm using JSON.NET

But I failed miserably. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Are you facing challenge while serialization or deserialization?

Comment: As in a title and tagÆ while desarilization :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom converter which would check token type that has been read in the `ReadJson` method and substitute some default value for `test` when the token is of type `JArray` (assuming it can only be an array when the `test` object is "empty"):

```
public class Root
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(TestIgnoreEmptyListConverter))]
    public Test test { get; set; }
}

// .................

public class TestIgnoreEmptyListConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(Test).IsAssignableFrom(objectType) || objectType.IsArray;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var token = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (token is JArray)
            return default(Test);
        else
            return token.ToObject<Test>();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Q3S5hX

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON propert name does not match object's name. Serializer tries to serialize/deserialize using property name or attributes.

Change this to the right name

```
public Test test { get; set; }
```

Or use attribute to set json name for a property.

```
[JsonProperty("test")]
public Test objects { get; set; }
```

Or even better, refactor your code to respect C# conventions. (I suggest to rename fields to be more descriptive)

```
public class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("test")]
    public Test Test { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
    [JsonProperty("object_array1")]
    public List<int> IntArray { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("object_array2")]
    public List<string> StringArray { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Edited my post, but this it is not resolving an issue. It was just mistake in rewriting, sorry for that.